# How to override the payment methods template while display in checkout page in magento 2

Tags: overrides, payment-methods, magento2.2.2, custom-template

In Magento 1

/var/www/html/xxx/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml.

In Magento 2

What is the equivalent file for the above one in magento 2 and how to override it. Please provide me  a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just your informed Magento2.x using knockout js MVC structure.

**In Magento 2**

Checkout page payment methods list display in `list.html` and this file 
available at location `/xxx/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/payment-methods/list.html`

If need to override this file in your theme then copy core file at location

```
/xxx/app/design/frontend/{Your-Theme}/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/payment-methods/list.html
```

After run below commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I wish to add new payment methods and wish to customize  its look in checkout page

Comment: Yes if your add new payment methods It is is display on checkout page

Comment: But it is KO template, I did't know how to override it, Can you suggest

Comment: Have you created custom payment method? There are two files for eg

\app\code\AR\Newpayment\view\frontend\templates\form\Newpayment.phtml
\app\code\AR\Newpayment\view\frontend\web\template\payment\newpayment.html

Comment: I have created system configuration for my payment method in backend

Comment: I wish to show only two payment methods in checkout page one is COD and another one is my custom payment method like online payment

Comment: So , Can you tell the example how to customize it , If I customized whether it will affect default flow

Comment: If your customize  your custom payment method then it will affect default flow. For eg. your custom payment method display only India then you must be customize your custom payment method module files