# Magento 2 - Disable Custom Payment Method and Show Custom Message

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom, payment-methods

In my Observer I check the customer attribute for a value. If the value matches I disable the method.  This is working just fine in my observer:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DisablePayment implements ObserverInterface
{
  protected $_logger;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    LoggerInterface $logger
  ) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
  }

  /**
   * @param Observer $observer
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function execute( Observer $observer )
  {
    $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
    $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

    if($method_instance == 'payroll')
    {
      $customerAttribute = $this->getCustomAttribute();
      // enter the value of the customer attribute field here you are testing against
      if($customerAttribute == 'User')
      {
        $result->setData('is_available', false);
      }
    }
  }

  public function getCustomAttribute(){
     if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
       // enter the name of the field you want to check
       return $customerAtt = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getData('lastname');
     endif;
  }
}
```

I want to show a custom message if the payment is not supposed to show. I can't figure out how to show my custom message. When the method is disabled in my observer, I want to show a message to the user explaining that it was disabled and provide a reason why - ie. I'm sorry but your credit balance is XX and not enough for this transaction. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: which observer, you have using?

Comment: @Amit I am not sure what you mean but this is in events.xml    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="payroll_payment_method_is_active" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\DisablePayment" />
    </event>

Comment: Is it possible to use a controller to show the message?

Comment: I can show a message in my theme by using Magento_Checkout>web>template>payment-methods>list.html  Is there a way to only show a message for when my particular payment method is not active?  Also is there a way to add this to my payment module?

Comment: I will check at Monday and get back to you.

Comment: @Amit Thanks!  Just to try to be clear, when the customer attribute doesn't match the value I have in my observer, I want to show a message in place of my payment method saying that the method is not available to the customer.

I essentially have a credit line for the user (customer attribute) and if it is less than the total then the method doesn't show. I need to grab the total in my observer, do the math and then I want to show a message that says "Sorry, but you only have XXX left in your account and this method is not currently available.

Comment: @Amit Should I overwrite the payment method list in my module and KO to show the message if the method is not available?  Ideas how?

Comment: Have to work at Knockout payment method list file , see https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/223197/4564

Comment: @Amit - I am overwriting the payment method list and I can see that it works.  How to I use KO to check for the payment method and then show the message.  I am trying this: <!-- ko if: ((method.method_code + '_' + method.payment_code == "payroll_payroll") -->
    <h1>KO Works </h1>
    <!-- /ko -->

Comment: @Amit - KO above doesn't work.  How can I check for the payment code in my html template and if the code isn't there show the message?  Thanks!